# Is there any linux shellmenu available?

Tags: linux

I want that when certain users login they will have a menu instead of accessing the shell with some options that i will configure.
I've seen somewhere a perl script (using ncurses i think) that did this but i didn't saved the link and now i can't seem to find it anymore.
Anybody aware of anything like this available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have their shell execute a perl (or any kind of) script upon login by putting it in their ~/.bashrc file.  (make sure to put a & at the end of the command if you want the rest of the logon script to finish executing)

What kind of a menu are you wanting to create?

Comment: Just some simple stuff like a menu with: start/stop/restart service X. After a little Google i think I'll write a little bash script to do that using dialog and then replace their shell with this script as they don't need shell access, this menu will be enough.

Comment: Even better - if you do it that way, when they exit the script (or even ctrl-c) they will be logged out.

Comment: Just something to look out for.  A lot of apps requires a valid shell in order for the "system" or "exec" command to work in spawning off a start/stop request.  So, making the perl script the users "shell" may not work like you think.

Comment: better if it's .bash_profile, which gets run at login.  .bashrc happens for every shell and anything interactive can cause problems

Answer (score 3):

If you want something curses based, check out the linux dialog command (http://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog).  You can achieve menu-like functionality using this with little development on your part.  It's also pretty much self-contained.  As far as I can tell, you only need the dialog binary file, so you don't have to load a bunch of extra software on your machine if you don't want to.  Most of the time, I simply write a shell script using the echo command to print out a menu, the read command to read a choice by the user, and a case statement to process the choice and run the task associated with it.  Then I call this menu script from the startup file (.profile or .login depending on which shell is used).  This isn't fool-proof, but it is quick and dirty.